# Role of the Report section in Neuron (journal)?

Tags: journals

The journal Neuron has a section called **Report**.

I am having hard time finding the answer to the following question:

- What is the intended role of this section?
- Are this papers written by submission or by invitation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more accurate answers can be obtained directly through communicating with the said journal editors.

Comment: Is there a criteria that topics should be closed for that reason? 

If a lot of people get the answer here and if sufficient time is saved from the editors and the overall knowledge of the public is increased then this is a good public service.

Comment: It possibly asks for the summarized yet complete description on major contributions you are giving to the community. I am not sure. You might want to talk to editor of the journal.

Comment: Yes, the more out-of-the-can one is perhaps "The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a certain person’s preferences, **a given institution’s regulations**, the exact contents of your work or your personal values." However, I opted for a customized one so that I can put the suggested action into the closing reason.